# Scala combinations function not terminating

Tags: scala, scalaz

I need to generate the combinations for a list of 30,000 items using scalas combinations method on a stream / list

```
1 to 30000.toStream.combinations(2).size
```

This function never completes. When I try the same operation in python

```
r = list(range(1,30000))
z = itertools.combinations(r, 2)
%time sum(1 for _ in z)
```

The operation completes in 26.2 seconds.

Whats going on here? How can I generate the combinations of a very large list in scala?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know why the implementation in stdlib takes so long. However, this straightforward implementation (specialized to pairs and `List`s), is comparable to the Python one:

```
def combinations2[A](l: List[A]): Iterator[(A, A)] =
  l.tails.flatMap(_ match {
    case h :: t => t.iterator.map((h, _))
    case Nil => Iterator.empty
  })
```

Then

```
scala> {
     |   val t0 = System.nanoTime
     |   val res = combinations2((1 to 30000).toList).size
     |   val secs = (System.nanoTime - t0) / 1000000.0
     |   s"$res (computed in $secs seconds)"
     | }
res11: String = 449985000 (computed in 24992.487638 seconds)
```

Comment: Note that the `combination` method specifies that only one occurrence for each combination should be given. So `List(1, 2, 2).combinations(2).toList.ordered == List(List(1, 2), List(2, 1))`. I don't know whether OP is interested in this property or not, but it will certainly take some time longer to run `distinct` on your output (although probably still much less time than stdlib's implementation).

Answer (score 7):

@TomasMikula provided an alternative, I was interested to see why `combinations` was inefficient in generating the result.

A quick look using Mission Control and Flight Recorder revealed the problem:

[image: Mission Control]

The `CombinationItr` iterator invokes `IndexedSeqOptimized.slice` each iteration of `next()`. `ArrayBuilder` creates a new builder each time it runs with number of elements it needs to iterate, which means it will allocate 30,000 `Array[Int]`, each of them containing n - 1 elements, causing a total of 11.10GB in a 1 minute sample. This causes massive amounts of GC pressure and is generally not very effecient.

Comment: This a great explanation. Thanks a ton.